# Map values to list

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have an `Map<String,Integer>` which is sorted by value like that

```
  public void sortList(Map<String,Integer> map){
         set = map.entrySet();
        list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(set);
        Collections.sort( list, (o1, o2) -> (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() ));

    }
```

I need to copy all values to new list

```
  word_used = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());
```

but it saves in non-sorted order

Comment: TreeMap. I need it, to sort by values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First extract the list, sort it and then create a new list with it.

```
List<Integer> tmp = map.values();
Collections.sort(tmp);
word_used = new ArrayList<Integer>(tmp);
```

---

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

```
word_used = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values()
                                      .stream()
                                      .sorted()
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you sort that `list` you created from the `entrySet`, it doesn't change the order of the entries in the original `Map`. You'll have to return the `list` from your `sortList` method if you want a `List` of the sorted values.

`map.values()` will not return the values sorted, since the values are not kept in any specific order in the `Map`. Some `Map` implementations (such as `TreeMap`) keep the keys sorted, but not the values.